Distribution of perfect numbers for a semiprime
Given a semiprime with a length of 120 digits (397bit):
is it possible to meet any assumptions about perfect numbers (prime factors with same length, 199+199bit) for this number?
I have made an observation that numbers with higher first digits (28... and higher) statistically produce more prime factors that have a total length of 396 bit where smaller first digits (1..) more often are factored to primes, that have a total length of < 396 bit.
So I am deriving from that that the higher numbers would have a higher perfect number probability as there are more factors have a "correct" total length. The smaller first digits are showing more prime factors that have a "too short" total length and cannot return a perfect prime.
Is there any mathematical evidence if higher first digits will have a higher probability for perfect numbers?

Can you clarify your question? "Perfect number" has a standard mathematical meaning, but I think you mean something else—different wording (and perhaps an explicit definition) would be helpful.

I have different semiprimes. All of them have the same length of 120 digits. I am looking for two prime factors of such a number. Both need to have the exact same bitlength of 199 bits. My observation is that semiprimes starting with a higher digit (26..) have a higher probability for primes q,p that have a total bitlength of 2*199 (p.bitlength + q.bitlength = 398) where smaller numbers tend to have primes with a total bitlength of 397 bit. Im asking myself if there is a mathematical reason for that and how it is possible to identify semiprimes that will resolve into the "correct" length

I have removed the [perfect-numbers] tag, as this question is not related to numbers $N$ such that $\sigma(N)=2N$, where $\sigma(x)$ is the classical sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$. Such numbers are called perfect, by standard mathematical terminology.

The $199$ bit numbers range from $2^{198}$ to $2^{199}-1$.  When you multiply two of them you get a number in the range $2^{396}$ to $2^{398}-2^{200}+1$ which can have $397$ or $398$ bits.  To get a $397$ bit result you need to be in the bottom part of the range, so one would expect smaller primes to allow the other factor to have $199$ bits.  Since $2^{198} \approx 4.017 \cdot 10^{59}$ your numbers starting with $28$ have $198$ bits, not $199$

Im actually looking for the 398 bit result - which starting numbers should I be looking at then?
Actually numbers starting with 28 can have 199 bits. Example:
264188901067326832046652468489765799388008160002756273362108959991995348584602517831800599500456961923959141615754409437
which factors to 38491027635342685435052159060902695579398842246465862112238221636485544609440858779 and 6863648941000137044620127240945308903 having 275 and 123 bits -> 398 in total

Your number that starts with $28$ has only $397$ bits.  If you multiply binary numbers with $a$ and $b$ bits the product has $a+b-1$ bits if there is no carry or $a+b$ if there is a carry.  If what you want is the sum of the number of bits of the factors to be $398$ you should say that.  When you say a number has $398$ bits we think you are talking of the number of bits from converting that number to base $2$.
